# How to reposition some blocks on smaller screen?

Tags: html, css

I have a html and css layout that looks very common: one large content row and sidebar.
[image]

Have a look here. Blocks 1,2,3 go in the main part and 4,5,6 blocks go into sidebar. Now what I want to do is to reposition these blocks on smaller screen - say on a tablet that way.

[image]

So I just in hesitation how to put that blue block at the bottom of 4 and 5. 
So far I tried to create it using flex but it seems so hard as structure wont allow this.

[Here is codepen example](https://codepen.io/Amduscias/pen/dybdrjP)

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
/*   height: 320px; */
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#col1 {
  flex-basis: 80%;
}

#col2 {
  flex-basis: 20%;
  position: relative
}

#another-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#wig1 {
  background-color: red;
  height: 80px
}
#wig2 {
  background-color: green;
  height: 150px
}
#wig3 {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 40px
}
#wig4 {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100px
}
#wig5 {
  background-color: purple;
  height: 100px
}
#wig6 {
  background-color: magenta;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: auto;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="col1">
    <div id="wig1">1</div>
    <div id="wig2">2</div>
    <div id="wig3">3</div>
  </div>
  <div id="col2">
    <div id="another-wrapper">
      <div id="wig4">4</div>
      <div id="wig5">5</div>
      <div id="wig6">
        <span>6</span>
        <span>6</span>
        <span>6</span>
        <span>6</span>
        <span>6</span>
        <span>6</span>
        <span>6</span>
        <span>6</span>
        <span>6</span>
        <span>6</span>
        <span>6</span>
        <span>6</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can i use bootstrap??

Comment: I use material-ui. The problem lies in structure I believe

Comment: You can use [CSS GRID] (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) to solve your problem

Comment: I would love to understand how to do that in plain css and html

Comment: Considering you want to achieve the layout  as displayed in image #2 in smaller devices..
 If you want to keep the html structure same across devices, and achieve the layout, css grid is the easier way this can be made possible..

Comment: HTML structure of course can be initially changed. If that solves the question

Comment: My case doesnt work with grid. Thanks for idea

Comment: @sgko See my answer, why doesn't your case work with grid?

Comment: The problem is that any block can be of different height, and in your realisation each block in the main column corresponds to any block in sidebar. But my blocks can vary in height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a perfect job for CSS Grid:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "one two" "three four" "five six";
}

.grid>div {
  border: solid 2px green;
}

.grid>div:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: lightblue;
  grid-area: one;
}

.grid>div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: yellow;
  grid-area: two;
}

.grid>div:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  grid-area: three;
}

.grid>div:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: khaki;
  grid-area: four;
}

.grid>div:nth-child(5) {
  background-color: teal;
  grid-area: five;
}

.grid>div:nth-child(6) {
  background-color: brown;
  grid-area: six;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-areas: "one one" "two two" "four six" "five six" "three six";
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 3fr;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This :

```
<style>
  * {
     box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  #wrapper {
     border: 1px solid black;
  }
  @media screen and (min-width: 900px){
     #col2 {
       width: 20%;
       float: left;
     }
     #col1 {
       width: 80%;
       float: left;
     }
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 900px){
    #another {
      width: 40%;
      float: left;
    }
    #wig3 {
      position: absolute;
      width: 39%;
      top: 439px;
    }
  }

  #wig1 {
     background-color: red;
     height: 80px
  }
  #wig2 {
     background-color: green;
     height: 150px
  }
  #wig3 {
     background-color: blue;
     height: 40px
  }
  #wig4 {
     background-color: yellow;
     height: 100px
  }
  #wig5 {
     background-color: purple;
     height: 100px
  }
  #wig6 {
     background-color: magenta;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
  }
</style>
<div id="wrapper">
 <div id="col1">
   <div id="wig1">1</div>
   <div id="wig2">2</div>
   <div id="wig3">3</div>
 </div>
 <div id="col2">
   <div id="another">
    <div id="wig4">4</div>
    <div id="wig5">5</div>
   </div>
   <div id="wig6">
    <span>6</span>
    <span>6</span>
    <span>6</span>
    <span>6</span>
    <span>6</span>
    <span>6</span>
    <span>6</span>
    <span>6</span>
    <span>6</span>
    <span>6</span>
    <span>6</span>
    <span>6</span>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```